# Make Correspondence between Two different Pointers to the same Class

Tags: c++, algorithm

Suppose I have a city map that I want to make a copy of. The problem is that `from` and `to` in the `road` class are pointers in memory for that particular `cityMap` object. Making a new object independent of the one being copied will mean each city will have a different pointer value. What is an intelligent way to make a correspondence between roads in the to-be-copied `cityMap` and the new `cityMap` I created in the `copy` method?

Idea 1 (slower and I think it's ugly) is to make `map<road *, road *>`.

Idea 2 (which I feel is ugly since it adds to a lower class a member not needed for the implementation of that class as a concept but is O(1) lookup time after O(N) construction time) is to have a member in `road` that is `road *correspondingRoad`. Then, I can merely say `newRoad->to = oldRoad->to->correspondingRoad`.

Is there a nice way to set all this up? I would like O(1) lookup time (not a map), not much construction time (not a map), and to leave the road class untouched by what an unrelated class wants from it. That is, a newly created road corresponding to the exact same road is not part of the concept of a road, it is only part of the concept of copying a city map.

```
class cityMap
{
public:
    vector<roads *> allRoads    // all raods in the area
    vector<city *> cities;      // all the cities in the area
    cityMap *copy();            // makes a copy of the entire map
};

class roads
{
public:
    city *from, *to;
}

class city
{
public:
    vector<raod *> roads;       // roads from this city to another city
}
```

Comment: What about storing the index instead of the pointer?

Comment: Indices will not work here, something I meant to mention, because cities are demolished and constructed. Thus, keeping all indices valid would be quite an overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, I think you want to perform a *deep copy* of your city map, and are looking for a way in which you can efficiently ensure that the relationships between your new objects are the same as the relationships between the old ones.

I agree that idea 2, having an additional member in a road, to represent the mapping from old to new, is horrible. However I can't see a lot wrong with idea 1, using a `map` to represent the mapping from the original road to the new road, although I think you will also need to map from old to new cities as well as from old to new roads. If you have a `map`, it will only be a temporary map, needed only during your `copy` method, and your operations on the new city map will probably take more time than the copy. Moreover a `map` is a library class so is going to be pretty well optimized. If you are in C++11 (or have access to boost), you can use a hash map, in the shape of an `unordered_map`, which gives you average O(1) rather than logarithmic lookup. This approach gives:

```
using std::vector;
using std::unordered_map;

class road;
class city;

class cityMap
{
public:
    vector<road *> allRoads;    // all raods in the area
    vector<city *> cities;      // all the cities in the area
    cityMap *copy()             // makes a copy of the entire map
    {
        cityMap* pNewCityMap = new cityMap;
        // create new cities, building up old city to new city map
        unordered_map<city*, city*> city2city;
        for(city* pOldCity: cities) {
            city* pNewCity = new city(*pOldCity);
            pNewCityMap->cities.push_back(pNewCity);
            city2city[pOldCity] = pNewCity;
        }
        // create new roads, building up old road to new road map
        unordered_map<road*, road*> road2road;
        for(road* pOldRoad: allRoads) {
            road* pNewRoad = new road(city2city[pOldRoad->from], city2city[pOldRoad->to]);
            pNewCityMap->allRoads.push_back(pNewRoad);
            road2road[pOldRoad] = pNewRoad;
        }
        // fix up roads in new cities
        for(city* pNewCity: pNewCityMap->cities) {
            for(road*& pNewRoad: pNewCity->roads) {
                pNewRoad = road2road[pNewRoad];
            }
        }
        return pNewCityMap;
    }
};

class road
{
public:
    city *from, *to;
    road(city* _from, city* _to) : from(_from), to(_to) {}
};

class city
{
public:
    vector<road *> roads;       // roads from this city to another city
};
```

An alternative approach is inspired by celtschk's comment, and is to use an index to represent a road. In this case the city map can still return a `road` class, but has to internally store its roads in terms of indexes. A sketch implementation follows.

```
using std::pair;
typedef size_t roadnum;

class city2
{
public:
    vector<roadnum> roads;       // roads from this city to another city
};

class road2
{
public:
    city2 *from, *to;
    road2(city2* _from, city2* _to) : from(_from), to(_to) {}
};

class cityMap2
{
    vector<pair<size_t, size_t>> allRoads;    // all raods in the area, pairs of city indices
public:
    vector<city2 *> cities;      // all the cities in the area
    cityMap2 *copy();             // makes a copy of the entire map

    size_t GetNumberRoads() const { return allRoads.size(); }
    road2 GetRoad(size_t which) const
    {
        const pair<size_t, size_t>& citycity = allRoads[which];
        return road2(cities[citycity.first], cities[citycity.second]);
    }
};
```

Comment: An unsorted map is the perfect strategy! It has the ease-of-use brought by a standard container, omits modification of the road class, and has the speed of the "hack" solution of modifying the road class on average.